# Using Amazon Product Advertising API to get special "Sale" price

Tags: amazon-product-api

I have been successfully using the Amazon Product Advertising API to get nearly all data I need until I ran into this product and problem.

Most products when viewed on amazon display price list this

```
List Price:     $89.99
Price:  $81.10 & FREE Shipping. Details
```

I am able to put this pricing info with the API using ItemLookukp and a few different ResponseGroups.

But, In very few cases like this item

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B003BNZRY2/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003BNZRY2)

I see a Sale price as viewed from amazon website.

```
Safe T Sleep Classic Sleepwrap Baby Swaddle For Bassinets, Cribs and Single Beds
by Safe T Sleep
30 customer reviews
Price:  $133.99
Sale:   $99.99 & FREE Shipping. FREE Returns. Details
You Save:   $34.00 (25%)
```

...and there is no sign of this sale price in the data returned from the API.  Below is part of the reponse I usually get pricing info from in the "Offers"  ResponseGroup.

```
[Offers] => ZendService\Amazon\OfferSet Object
    (
        [LowestNewPrice] => 9449
        [LowestNewPriceCurrency] => USD
        [LowestUsedPrice] => 
        [LowestUsedPriceCurrency] => 
        [TotalNew] => 3
        [TotalUsed] => 0
        [TotalCollectible] => 0
        [TotalRefurbished] => 0
        [Offers] => Array
            (
                [0] => ZendService\Amazon\Offer Object
                    (
                        [MerchantId] => 
                        [MerchantName] => 
                        [GlancePage] => 
                        [Condition] => New
                        [OfferListingId] => 
                        [Price] => 13399
                        [CurrencyCode] => USD
                        [Availability] => Usually ships in 24 hours
                        [IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

94.49 or 9449 is actually the lowest new price but does not include free shipping. 
The API response says the lowest free shipping price is at 133.99 which is NOT actually true.

The lowest free shipping price is the sale price which is $99.99 which is what I want.
But the $99.99 Sale Price is no where to be found in any of the ReponseGroups.

I am using the itemlookup and looking up but ASIN.  In this case this ASIN is B003BNZRY2

Is it possible to get the "Sale" price using the API?  If so, how and where do I find it?
I've looked through responses of every related ResponseGroup and can't find it.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I guess I don't feel so bad since I could not figure this out. It's been 5 days and still no one has attempted to answer this.  :(

Comment: where do you see that shipping is included on each price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try "OfferFull" ResponseGroup.

```
          <OfferListing>
        <OfferListingId>OBSJghi2hPtiDv6V%2Bk9SIW%2B6u5JBnttE5zmF%2BTaPuWNvenFvBhNAp4JJuuw0Wow9%2FQ%2BzY4cvL%2BwwA3L7GyRoxKCE6XhP1HZupFgiizwXEUQ7Oj21tKu%2B9SAExnEb5xsGpB9ByX6nEm72dlGCLkQeEw%3D%3D</OfferListingId>
        <Price>
          <Amount>13399</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$133.99</FormattedPrice>
        </Price>
        <SalePrice>
          <Amount>9999</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$99.99</FormattedPrice>
        </SalePrice>
        <AmountSaved>
          <Amount>3400</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$34.00</FormattedPrice>
        </AmountSaved>
```